# How secure are the notes stored alongside passwords in iOS?

Tags: ios, icloud, security, password, keychain

I am not discussing the Notes app, nor the [Secure Notes](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/keychain-access/kyca2268/mac) feature of the traditional Keychain Access on macOS - rather the NOTES section of Passwords found in the iOS Settings app. In looking for an answer to this I found [this quote](https://rawinfopages.co.uk/add-notes-to-passwords-on-the-iphone/):

> Apple says: “Just like your passwords, these notes are end‑to‑end encrypted and synced across your devices using iCloud Keychain.“

However, I can't find a source for this. Apple has [a page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secb0694df1a/web) that seems to suggest they are slightly more "available" than the passwords themselves:

> Keychain metadata (all attributes other than kSecValue) is encrypted with the metadata key to speed searches and the secret value (kSecValueData) is encrypted with the secret key. The metadata key is protected by the Secure Enclave but is cached in the Application Processor to allow fast queries of the keychain. The secret key always requires a round trip through the Secure Enclave.

The behaviour of Passwords seems to reflect this: you can search for the notes but not for the passwords themselves. I also notice that screenshots do not block the notes as they do the password. These differences imply they are generally not treated as securely as passwords - perhaps there are other compromises too. Many people use these for additional security details such as security questions. Has Apple provided any guarantees about their security?

Comment: They are stored *in* the keychain and the *whole* keychain is encrypted, so it stands to reason that the notes are as secure as your passwords.